# Umbraco check if node is still exist

Tags: c#, umbraco

Hello how to check in Umbraco that node that i get by Id is still exist

```
var node = new Node(id);
```

return object in anyway, but if I try read some properties I got exception.
Does anyone know Umbraco API function for check it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually just check:

`string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Name)`

A node should never have an empty name, so that way you know it's either unpublished or has been deleted.

It is a  workaround for the fact that the API has no other way of checking this.

Answer (score 2):

I use your code to display name of node but when I unpublish it then i have "Error loading Razor Script" . I thought that it will be null.

I use below code in razor macro:

```
@{

    var main = @Model.Down(1);  

    string value = @main.Name.ToString();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)){
        @value
    }
}
```

Working perfectly only when node is published

Comment: If the Name property is null you can't do ToString() on it, so you need to check for null first.